# Possible security risks in localization messages

Tags: security, localization

If a web application allows users to contribute translation messages in order to localize the application to a given language or locale, then what are the potential security risks involved in this. [Apart from social engineering which is an obvious one]

These translation messages are usually a collection of key-value pairs in some kind of format depending on the language/library etc. For example, PHP array files as in many OSS PHP applications, getetxt .po files  for apps using gettext, Yaml files in Rails, and many others.

Such translation data is then used to provide a new locale in the list of locales available for a site.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest this is kind of a strange question.  I will assume that you have read and understand the [OWASP top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Top_Ten_Project).  I assume you know how to protect your own server from attack.

That being said in my mind the most obvious attack against this translation system is persistent XSS which would allow an attacker to deface every website using this dataset.  Just saying "oah we htmlencode the values" isn't enough.  If you are supplying these data sets to a 3rd party you can't expect all of them to sanitize the data properly.   To make matters worse,  XSS is [an output problem](https://sitewat.ch/en/Blog/5),  you can't [HTML encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) the entire data set and expect it to be 100% safe because you have no idea how the data is going to be used within the HTML document.   The problem is the data may end up within a script tag or event,  and then the protection from html-encoding could be nullified entirely.   I always chuckle when I see someone using [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) to try and stop xss,  this is just the wrong approach.

In summation there really isn't a 100% solution to the problem,  but this will prevent most xss:

```
$var=htmlspecialchars($var,ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");
$var=rtrim($var,"\\");
```

Obviously the `rtrim()` is used to help prevent xss within a script tag.  If the string ends with a backslash you can break out of a quoted string,  backslashes are equally as dangerous as quote marks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm aware (to a degree) of the various attacks. The question doesn't say this, but I'm trying to look at this problem from a wider angle - most(all?) apps are designed with the assumption of a single point of control of the l10n data - I'm thinking of other scenarios say for example where l10n data is maintained by 3rd parties and made available say over a CDN.

Comment: @Basel Shishani you are grasping at straws.  I am concerned that you are spending too much time on exotic problems when at the end of the day is the simple issues that get people hacked to tears.  Persistent XSS is a very serious vulnerability that allows an attacker to introduce an iframe and exploit browsers or deface websites.

Comment: @Basel Shishani It should also be noted that in the vast majority of compromised websites i have cleaned up, the attacker used a sophisticated remote code execution on the server,  to introduce a simple iframe on the main page to exploit browsers.   Stored xss on the front page is the most valuable web application exploit to the vast majority of criminals.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you relinquish control of the content, you are effectively allowing any "authorized" content provider to add whatever they want to your UI.  Even if you prevent execution of potential code included in the content, you cannot prevent display of inappropriate text (or images) to users unless you screen that text at its entry point into your system.

One way to address this is via service contracts with the content providers that specify their obligations for content verification.  Depending on who the providers are, this may be enough to make you confortable with relinquishing control.  Otherwise, there's pretty much no substitute for a human with the application's owner organization approving all submitted content before it is approved for publication.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's safe to say that HTML elements in the "new" string can only be those that were in the old string, minus a few specific attributes such as `title` and `alt`.

Example:

- English string: `<strong title="Just a test">Hover this message</strong>`
- Dutch translation: `<strong title="Gewoon een test">Hang hier met de muis boven</strong>` - will be marked as safe
- Dutch translation: `<strong onmouseover="window.location='something';">Hang hier met de muis boven</strong>` will be invalidated by the filter

You would have to write a rather strong filter though, and always verify that no attributes were added, removed, and no HTML elements were added or removed. Also, always be careful with `"` and `'`.